Separating signals from two different objects
In the frequency range of 11.5 kHz-12.5 kHz, there is the signal from a person that I am looking for. I can see this signal too, but with a smaller amplitude in the ranges of 10.5 kHz-11.5 kHz and 12.5 kHz-13.5 kHz. But at the same time, if you look at the signal from the car, it is in the range of 15.5 kHz-16.5 kHz, and also with a smaller amplitude in the ranges of 14.5 kHz-15.5 kHz and 16.5 kHz-17.5 kHz and so on and reaches the range of 11.5 kHz-12.5 kHz, where there is a signal from a person. Due to the fact that the signal from the car is very large in amplitude, then at frequencies of 11.5 kHz-12.5 kHz it turns out to be equivalent to the signal from a person. I wanted to somehow separate these signals (if this is even possible). At first I thought to track the signal in the range of 11.5-12.5 kHz and then see if there is a signal with a large amplitude higher in the spectrum, so I will understand that this is a signal from the movement of the car. But then I realized that if a person is walking and a car is driving at the same time (the signal is present on both frequencies (11.5 kHz-12.5 kHz and 15.5 kHz-16.5 kHz), then I will not be able to separate these signals.
Below I will show these signals on graphs. The sampling frequency is 48 kHz. I made clean recordings of the signal without processing.
Then I did the following processing:

First, I take the band I need 11.5 kHz-12.5 kHz, by passing it through a bandpass filter.
Then, with a rejection filter, I cut out the band 11995-12005 Hz (there is a constant signal that I am not interested in).
Then I do detection (I take it by modulus) and build the signal envelope by passing it through a low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of 6 Hz.

Band 11.5-12.5 kHz. There are 2 signals from human movement (red), 4 signals from car movement (orange) and the first purple is human + car, and the second purple is just a car. Blue is just noise.

The same movements, only the band is 15.5-16.5 kHz

And two more of the same graphs, only here the first purple one is just a person, and the second purple one is a person + a car.


Is there a solution to this problem?
P.S. I can't get rid of these harmonics on a physical level. I tried, but I realized that they are there and will always be there.
